# MVC Form Validation | Custom "Validation Attribute" not receiving the right "value"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, attributes

**THE CONTEXT**

I have an MVC form that includes two date pickers, for which I have written a custom validation attribute to ensure that both selected dates are not in the past (>= today).

**THE PROBLEM**

The validation attribute works only for the first date but not for the second, because the value passed to the "value" object in the validation attribute is always reset to the value set in the form class (*HomeForm.cs*) constructor (*HomeForm( )*).

- **Example (VS + browser screenshot):**
  The picked date is the 10/08/2021 but the Object value for *dateB* is 16/08/2021.

[issue example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQyRE.jpg)

**THE CODE**

This is my **form** (*HomeForm.cs)*:

```
public class HomeForm

    {
        public HomeForm()
        {
            dateA = DateTime.Now.Date;
            TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0);
            dateB = DateTime.Now.Date + time;
        }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must select a departure date.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayName("Departure date:")]
        [DateTimeRange]

        public DateTime dateA { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must select a return date.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayName("Return date:")]
        [DateTimeRange]

        public DateTime dateB { get; set; }  
    };
```

A custom **Validation Attribute** "DateTimeRange" is applied to *dateA* and *dateB*:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]

    public class DateTimeRangeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        private readonly DateTime _today;
        public DateTimeRangeAttribute()
        {
            _today = DateTime.Now.Date;
        }
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {

            if (value is not DateTime)
                return new ValidationResult("Date format is not valid.");

            if (!IsValid((DateTime)value))
                return new ValidationResult("Chosen date is in the past.");

            if(value.ToString().Count() != 19)
                return new ValidationResult("Not a valid date. Choose a different one.");

            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        private bool IsValid(DateTime value)
        {
            value = value.Date;
            return value >= _today;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I can't see any issues in this validation code. The constructor is called before model binding occurs. After the object is constructed, the model binder will set every property. Maybe there is an issue at this point: check in your request header if you provide a form value for dateB. If there is no dateB in your POST request, the value remains at the value set in the constructor.

Comment: Can you post your view code? I'd say the problem is in the view, not in the validation attribute.